# Google SignIn and Logout using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I am using `webpack` for bundling my app which has multiple HTML pages. I would like to provide Social auth using Google and Facebook. I have been able to get the respective login buttons to render and also get the access token. 
This is what I have in my Login HTML (snippet for Google only):

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
          content="xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Now to implement logout, do I need to include this information on all of my other pages also - since logout could be called from any page ?

Or is there a better way to implement this?

Appreciate any help!